# Gneivas daas with fake social media accounts

Tags: internet, mussar-ethics, gezel-stealing, social-media

Many companies (and the US government) create fake social media (Facebook, Twitter etc.) accounts in order to make it look like people are talking about their product. I personally know several frum people who have done this. The question is, isn't this clearly forbidden because of gneivas daas?

Comment: are you assuming that using the internet and/or social media is mutar in the first place?

Comment: @Dan I think using this site assumes that, so yes.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The source for the concept/prohibition of geneivas da'as is the Mishnah in Chullin [93b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=93b&format=pdf) and the Gemara that follows. The common denominator in all of the cases is that one is causing another to be thankful or appreciative for something which isn't really there; thus "stealing" the other's appreciation.* It is not really relevant to most questions of business ethics.

*Example: Opening a fancy bottle of wine and giving the plausible implication that it was in a certain guest's honor when in reality you were going to open it anyway.